# Filehelper not capturing all errors in each row

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I have two fields in the class that is used by filehelper engine as below

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines]
public class CustomerClass
{ 
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "MM/dd/yyyy")]
    private DateTime EffectiveDate;

    [FieldNotEmpty]
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForRead)]
    private string CustomerID;
}
```

I am reading the csv file and invoking the filehelper validation using below code

```
var engine = new DelimitedFileEngine<CustomerClass>;
engine.Options.IgnoreFirstLines = 1;
engine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;
List<CustomerClass> Result = engine.ReadFile(filepath).ToList();
ErrorInfo[] errorInfo = engine.ErrorManager.Errors;
```

If my csv has errors in both EffectiveDate(date format wrong) and CustomerID(null value passed), only the 1st error is captured for each row.

How do i capture errors in all columns and not stop when the 1st error occurs?
I am using Filehelper 3.1.5

Thanks,

Comment: When the library found an error in a line does not continue parsing it because the rest of the line can be invalid so it goes to the next line, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), you can verify field by field:

```
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText("Pasta1.csv"))
    {
        var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            CustomerClass record = new CustomerClass();
            record.CustomerID = (string)csv.GetField(typeof(string), "CustomerID");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.CustomerID))
            {
                //CustomerID is null
            }

            if (!csv.TryGetField<DateTime>("EffectiveDate", out record.EffectiveDate))
            {
                //EffectiveDate incorrect
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @MarcosMeli mentioned in a comment:

> When the library found an error in a line does not continue parsing it
>   because the rest of the line can be invalid so it goes to the next
>   line

If you really need to report all errors, you need to use an [`AfterReadRecord`](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/EventsAndNotification/ReadEvents/) event and 
do much more of the processing by hand.

First, you need to change all your fields to `string` so that there are no errors.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines]
public class CustomerClass : 
{ 
    public string EffectiveDate;

    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForRead)]
    public string CustomerID;
}
```

Then you need to add an event and process all the validation there. Something like:

```
void Engine_AfterReadRecord(EngineBase engine, FileHelpers.Events.AfterReadEventArgs<UserInfoFromAd> e)
 {
     string allMyErrors = null;

     bool isDateValid = IsDateValid(e.Record.EffectiveDate);
     if (!isDateValid)
     {
        allMyErrors += "Date is invalid. ";
     }

     bool isCustomerIdValid = IsCustomerIDValid(e.Record.CustomerID);
     if (!isCustomerIdValid)
     {
        allMyErrors += "CustomerID is invalid. ";
     }

     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(allMyErrors))
         throw new Exception(allMyErrors);
 }
```